# Greenshot Storage Location

Tags: greenshot

The "greenshot.ini", "greenshot-defaults.ini", and "greenshot-fixed.ini" files are all pre-configured with the "OutputFilePath" and "OutputFileAsFullpath" variables set to "${USERPROFILE}\Greenshot\" prior to deploying the application to a workstation. Every time the application is launched, it is verified that the "Storage location" is set properly to the aforementioned variable. However, whenever a screen capture is saved, the "Storage location" is automatically changed to "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop" for whatever reason. Once the application is closed and re-launched, the "Storage location" is once again set to the proper value. This behavior is persistent. How can the "Storage location" value be set to where it will not change and/or cannot be changed?

Comment: Are you sure the USERPROFILE environment variable is set as expected? Does the Greenshot directory exist? Is Greenshot running with permissions to write there? This could be an issue with Greenshot not being able to access the desired location and thus fallling back to the default location. If that is the case, [Greenshot's log file](https://getgreenshot.org/faq/where-can-i-find-greenshots-log-file/) should hopefully provide some helpful information.

Comment: Yes, the %userprofile% environment variable is set as expected. Yes, the greenshot folder exists and the user has full permissions to it. I've tried all combinations of user-related environment variables and even manually specifying the path (ie. c:\users\jsmith\appdata\roaming\greenshot), but to no avail. The storage location is always set to the proper location (within the greenshot settings), but changes at time of capture for whatever reason. Unfortunately, there's no error-related information within the log file.

Comment: I did some more testing - the only way I found to reproduce a similar behavior is by setting the path to a non-existing directory (e.g. C:\doesnotexist\, which actually led to the path being reset to the desktop when using "save directly". I assume you are using the "save directly" destination? What happens if you use "save as", are you able to explicitly save to the desired location using that dialog?

Comment: Also, have you tried a different, non-user-specific location like C:\Windows\Temp\? Just to verify that the issue is not related to the user's environment variables or permissions?

Comment: Yes. I've tried "c:\windows\temp" as well as other custom location on local drives where the users have full control ("d:\testing", "e:\testing"). Sadly, it doesn't matter where I attempt to set the storage location and with any user, it always reverts back to the local user desktop. Very strange.